# Python: local variable referenced before assignment after the assignment in a for-loop

Tags: python

I know this is a common question but I could not find the solution for my case. I have gotten a problem while a for-loop in Python. When I run a program with this piece

```
for j in range(len(line1)- 3):
    print 'j =', j
    spl1 = spline(line1[j], line1[j + 1], line1[j + 2], line1[j + 3], t, Nu)

print 'spl1 ='
matrix.show(spl1)
```

i get an output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\work\curvature\test\twisted\cardinal_spline.py", line 272, in <module> main()
File "D:\work\curvature\test\twisted\cardinal_spline.py", line 111, in main 
matrix.show(spl1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'spl1' referenced before assignment
```

Moreover, it does not print j-variable. I cannot see any mistake there. The "spl1" is assigned in the for-loop but it looks like the interpreter just skips it.

please point on the mistake.

Comment: why do you update the variable `spl1` in a loop? Its value will be overwritten in each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for-loop doesn't get executed at all due to `len(line1) <= 3` in some cases, so `spl1` isn't assigned.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, loops do not hold separate scope, so the `spl1` variable *will* be set "globally" if the loop is entered.

The line1 variable likely was likely 3 or fewer characters long, so the loop was never entered, thus the variable was never assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the length of your `line1` is less than or equal to 3. (`range(0)` returns an empty list as does `range(-1)`, etc.) Because of that, your for loop doesn't have anything to iterate over and therefore it doesn't execute that block of code.